# Objective-C protocol syntax

Tags: objective-c, syntax, protocols

Here are 2 lines of code from Apple's own SimpleStocks sample code (`APLSimpleStockView.m`)

```
NSInteger dataCount = [self.dataSource graphViewDailyTradeInfoCount:self];
NSArray *sortedMonths = [self.dataSource graphViewSortedMonths:self];
```

The first code line above looks like "dataSource" is the recipient of message `graphViewDailyTradeInfoCount:self` (which returns an `NSInteger`).

The second line of code above looks like "dataSource" is now the recipient of message `graphViewSortedMonths:self` (which returns an `NSArray *`).

The only reference to dataSource I can find (in `APLSimpleStockView.h`) has it being a property, not an object/class instance? How come I can send a property a message? I thought I can only get and set a property's value?

The end result of the code is that after line 1, `dataCount` contains a number, and after line 2, `sortedMonths` contains an array of sorted month names. But where does this behaviour come from, since I cant find any place in the sample where `dataSource` causes anything to be returned when sent a message.

Is `self.dataSource` acting as both a getter and a setter here?

Comment: Note that the 'messages' are `graphViewDailTradeInfoCount:` and `graphViewSortedMonths:`.  The `self` is an argument, not a part of the message.  Note also that each of those lines of code is 3 expressions;  `self.dataSource`, the call to the method, and the assignment to a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought I can only get and set a property's value?

That's correct, but what's the value of a property? In this case it's an object, and you can definitely send a message to an object.

The code is equivalent to using the getter for the property, assigning the result to a variable, and then sending the message:

```
WhateverClassTheDataSourceIs * dS = self.dataSource;
NSInteger dataCount = [dS graphViewDailyTradeInfoCount:self];
```

The additional assignment just isn't necessary.

(Your code could also be written

```
[[self dataSource] graphViewDailyTradeInfoCount:self];
```

If that makes it clearer for you.)

Comment: Aha! "...the value of a property? ..in this case is an object". That made a piece of the puzzle fall into place.

But another gap has opened up. In the alternate syntax you offer, it now looks like dataSource is being used as a message to object self. My brain is now going: dataSource is both an object AND a message.

This is pretty tough stuff for an old BASIC programmer :-)

Comment: `[self dataSource]` is sending a message (`dataSource`) to `self`. The message results in a method, also called `dataSource`, being called, and the return value of that method is an object. In everyday conversation, we can talk about `dataSource` itself being an object, glossing over those ubiquitous intermediate steps.

Answer (score 0):

> How come I can send a property a message?

A property is just a promise to provide accessor methods for a given name. If the property is `foo`, the accessors are typically `-foo` and `-setFoo:`. So, in this case, `self.dataSource` returns an object that receives the message.

If you look at the `APLSimpleStockView` interface, you'll see the property declared as a pointer to an object:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet id<APLSimpleStockViewDataSource> dataSource;
```

That means that `dataSource` is an `id` (that is, a pointer to an object) that implements the `APLSimpleStockViewDataSource` protocol. Also, it's marked as an outlet so that you can set it in Interface Builder. Accordingly, `self.dataSource` returns an `id` (again, an object pointer) that refers to the view's data source.

> Is "self.dataSource acting as both a getter and a setter here?

No, it's just a getter returning the data source object.

Comment: Another "aha!!", thank you. In my readings so far the examples of @property statements were kept simple, and mostly defined simple (i.e. BOOL) values. I completely overlooked that some of these values were objects (i.e. NSInteger), and that a property could be an object.

Comment: @WS Properties work fine for plain old data types like `int`, but they're even better for objects because the accessors take care of retaining and releasing the objects. This isn't such a big deal under ARC, but when they were introduced properties were a big step forward in Objective-C memory management.